# WPF: Toggle multiple Buttons by dragging the mouse over them

Tags: wpf, mouseover, togglebutton

Is it possible to toggle the state of multiple ToggleButtons by dragging the mouse over them (with the left mouse button hold down)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ToggleButton Content="ToggleButton" MouseEnter="ToggleButtonMouseEnter" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

private void ToggleButtonMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton tb = (System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton)sender;
     if(e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) tb.IsChecked = !tb.IsChecked;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything in the box that would support this, but you should be able to subscribe to [MouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mousemove.aspx) and toggle the state on if the button is pressed.

Comment: Thanks. But when I click on one ToggleButton and drag over to the next Button the second Button does not receive the MouseMove-Event. Maybe because the first Button "catched" the events?

Comment: @user1130329 Yeah - if you're clicking ON the button, you'll need to handle it yourself - the buttons capture the mouse by default, so the events would all happen in the first button.  You likely need to track mousemove in that case.

Comment: Stupid question: how do I track mousemove then?

Comment: @user1130329 Subscribe to it on the toggle button -  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mousemove.aspx